# knockoutjs how to call computed to internal object?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have knockoutjs  binding to JSON object

```
var SettingsModel = function(globalSettings) {
    var self = this;
    if  (globalSettings == null)
    {
         globalSettings = {"v1":null,"v2":null};                  
    }
    self.globalSettings = ko.observable(globalSettings);
    self.v3 = ko.computed(function(){
                    var dd = self.globalSettings().v1;
                    var dd1 = self.globalSettings().v2;
                    return self.globalSettings().v1 * 3;
            });
};

<input type="text" data-bind="value: globalSettings().v1" 
       id="MStartTime" placeholder="Choose date" class="form-control" />
```

computed is call only once during init. How to make it work for Json property is changed or just call computed all the time ?

Comment: You will have to make them `observable`

Comment: yes I have self.globalSettings = ko.observable(globalSettings); but it not work for internal properties

Comment: You need to convert that object into a object with observables then, look at mapping plugin

Comment: @a3code By *them* I meant the properties of `globalSettings`

Answer (score 0):

wild guess, but by principle shouldnt it be enought to "register" self.globalSettings() to listen for it ? like :

```
self.v3 = ko.computed(function(){

                self.globalSettings();
                var dd = self.globalSettings().v1;
                var dd1 = self.globalSettings().v2;
                return self.globalSettings().v1 * 3;
});
```

so everytime a property like globalSettings().v1 changes, the observed globalSettings() changes and the computed gets triggered

Comment: ko does not work like that. The observable globalSettings will not notify when its properties are updated

Comment: maybe you have luck with the SettingsModel.globalSettings.extend({ notify: 'always' }); -- http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html at the bottom "force observables to notify"

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make the properties `observable`s, either with a [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) or like this:

```
var SettingsModel = function(globalSettings) {
    var self = this;
    if  (globalSettings == null)
    {
         //create observables here
         globalSettings = {"v1":ko.observable(null),"v2":ko.observable(null)};
    }
    self.globalSettings = ko.observable(globalSettings);
    self.v3 = ko.computed(function(){
                    var dd = self.globalSettings.v1(); //notice the parenthesis
                    var dd1 = self.globalSettings.v2();
                    return self.globalSettings.v1() * 3;
            });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If the gobalSettings object is hard to change into observables etc you can go around the problem with using a dummy observable and triggers its `notifySubscribers` when the object mutates

http://jsfiddle.net/5gVFK/2